# What kind of Data is fed into tradebots?

Tags: trading

I always assumed were just fed news headlines and historical stock data to make their decision to buy or sell.
But recently I have found out that neural networks have a bad time handling big sets of data.
So what kind of data is fed into these programs nowadays?

Comment: "neural networks have a bad time handling big sets of data" Can you clarify what the exact claim you heard was? Big feature sets? Big training sets?

Comment: Well big inputs exponentially increase the amount of neurons you need. You can push a lot of individual datasets through the network of course, but the datasets should be small to get results

Comment: @user2741831 nn's deal with huge datasets all the time. you seem to be vaguely hinting at the curse of dimensionality but all algos suffer when you have a large p  (features) without a large n (rows) of data